# Rear door on Matrix won't stay up

Tags: toyota, matrix

The rear door on my 2005 Toyota Matrix no longer stays up. It got gradually worse over time but now won't stay up at all. Is there anything I can do to fix it or will I need to take it in?

Answer (score 4):

Replace rear door struts. You can use a vise grip on the strut shaft to hold the door open for the time being.

[Rear strut replacement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtMQ4q_vhPQ)

Comment: good answer, or a piece of wood cut to length. But replacement is the answer - they are NOT repairable.